# Homework question regarding survival models

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

> $1.$ Derive $e_x, e_{x:\bar n}$ **directly**, if $X \sim U(0, w)$ with $x = 20, n = 30, w = 100$.
> $2$. Derive $e_x, e_{x:\bar n}$ **directly**, if $X \sim \operatorname{Exp}(\lambda)$ $(E(x) = \lambda = 80)$ with $x = 20$ and $n = 30$.

I have an idea on how to solve this but I am not sure if it is the right approach.
For $1)$, we know that $tpx= 1-\frac{t}{80}$

In order to find ex I could use the sum from $k=1$ to $100-x(tpx)$.

This would give me $100-x-\frac{(100-x)(-x+101)}{160}$.

I am not sure if this right, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misunderstanding some basic concepts here.  $x = 20$ represents a life aged $20$, and you are asked for the expected curtate future lifetime of this life.  In other words, you are interested in the average **additional** whole number of years lived by this life.  That is the meaning of the symbol $e_x = e_{20}$.  If the symbol had been $\overset{\circ}{e}_{20}$, this is the expected complete future lifetime of $(20)$.

Next, the symbol $\require{enclose}e_{x:\enclose{actuarial}{n}}$ represents the expected curtate future lifetime of $(x)$ *within the next $n$ years*.  In other words, if $(x)$ survives less more than $n$ years, the $n$-year curtate future lifetime is $n$.

With these concepts in mind, we have $$e_x = \operatorname{E}[K_x] = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k \Pr[K_x = k],$$ where $K_x$ is the curtate future lifetime random variable for a life aged $x$.  Because $K_x$ is a random variable with nonnegative support, we can also write this as $$e_x = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \Pr[K_x \ge k] = \sum_{k=1}^\infty {}_k p_x.$$  In a similar fashion, we have $$\require{enclose}e_{x:\enclose{actuarial}{n}} = \operatorname{E}[K_x \wedge n] = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \min(k, n) \Pr[K_x = k] = \sum_{k=1}^n k \Pr[X_k = k] + \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty n \Pr[X_k = k].$$  We can also write this as $$\require{enclose}e_{x:\enclose{actuarial}{n}} = \sum_{k=1}^n {}_k p_x.$$  Note the change in the upper index of summation.

I will illustrate the solution for the second question, in which the future lifetime random variable for a life at birth (age $0$) is exponential with mean $\lambda$.  Thus, given survival to age $x$, the complete future lifetime random variable $T_x$ is also exponential with mean $\lambda$, due to the memorylessness property:  $$\Pr[T_x > t] = \frac{\Pr[T_0 > t+x]}{\Pr[T_0 > x]} = \frac{e^{-(t+x)/\lambda}}{e^{-x/\lambda}} = e^{-t/\lambda}, \quad t > 0.$$

Therefore, the curtate future lifetime random variable $K_x$ of $(x)$ is $$\Pr[K_x = k] = \Pr[k \le T_x < k+1] = (1 - e^{-(k+1)/\lambda}) - (1 - e^{-k/\lambda}) = e^{-k/\lambda}(1 - e^{-1/\lambda}).$$  This happens to be a geometric random variable with $1$-year survival probability $e^{-1/\lambda}$.

Then $${}_k p_{20} = \Pr[K_{20} \ge k] = \sum_{j=k}^\infty \Pr[K_{20} = j] = e^{-k/\lambda} = e^{-k/80},$$ and $$e_{20} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty {}_k p_{20} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-k/80} = \frac{1}{e^{1/80} - 1}.$$

We also have $$\require{enclose}e_{20:\enclose{actuarial}{30}} = \sum_{k=1}^{30} {}_k p_{20} = \sum_{k=1}^{30} e^{-k/80} = \frac{1-e^{-30/80}}{e^{1/80} - 1} \approx 24.8608.$$

Now that I have illustrated the solution for this part of your question, I leave the uniform case to you.  If you have any further questions, please let me know.

Comment: I am working on the normal distribution problem so I found that P(K(x)=k) gives me 1/80 which follows De Morve's Law so would ex= (w-x-1)/2, I'm not sure if this is right I am still trying to understand the basics of this.

Comment: @LilyanS The first part doesn't specify a normal distribution for the lifetime random variable.  It is a **uniform** distribution.  Don't use DeMoivre's Law; the question explicitly states to do the calculation directly.  $\Pr[K_{20} = k] = \frac{1}{80}$ for $k \in \{1, \ldots, 80\}$.  So $${}_k p_{20} = 1 - \frac{k}{80}.$$  Then what is $$\sum_{k=1}^{80} {}_k p_{20}?$$  Do you know how to evaluate this sum?  Hint:  $$\sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$$  And how would you calculate $$\sum_{k=1}^{30} {}_k p_{20}?$$